# Using a class's properties without having to write its name down every time

Tags: class, kotlin, properties

```
fun eval(expr: Expr): Int =
        when (expr) {
            is Num -> expr.value
            is Sum -> expr.left + expr.right
        }

interface Expr
class Num(val value: Int) : Expr
class Sum(val left: Expr, val right: Expr) : Expr
```

I would like to ideally use `value`, `left`, and `right` without having to call `expr` everytime. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `with` scope function is for.

```
fun eval(expr: Expr): Int = with (expr) {
        when (this) {
            is Num -> value
            is Sum -> left + right
        }
    }
```